# What are those metal discs at the base of some walls?

Tags: plumbing, walls

Here's an example from a shower stall at work.

[image: metal disc on wall]

I've seen them in other types of walls, including exterior ones.

Answer (score 27):

Plumbing pipe cleanout cover. You can remove the silver coverplate and you’ll have access to the sanitary drain pipe.

Comment: You also see plastic ones for getting at the electric wiring, often with junctions behind them.